# Ember application.hbs template child components not reloading

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am trying to implement a nav bar that displays either `Sign in` or `Sign out` depending on a boolean value in an Ember Service that I have injected into the `application` route (defined in `routes/application.js`).

I also read [this](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-practice-for-a-dynamic-menu-bar/9094) and it reaffirms my choice of the service approach of handling state.

Now the question and problem is that the child components are not updating when I redirect from one route to another. If the link says `Sign in`, when I successfully authenticate and sign in, the link will still say `Sign in`. It's only when I refresh the page does the link text change to `Sign out`. The `Sign out` link behavior is the same.

Code in `application.hbs`:

```
  {{nav-bar isAuthenticated=isAuthenticated}} ==> seems like only loaded once
  {{outlet}}
```

Code for the sign-in and sign-out links in `nav-bar.hbs`:

```
  {{log isAuthenticated }} ==> only prints upon page load, doesn't print on route changes
  {{#if isAuthenticated}}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      {{#link-to 'logout' tagName="li" class="nav-item"}}<a class="nav-link" href="">Logout</a>{{/link-to}}
    </ul>
  {{else}}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      {{#link-to 'login' tagName="li" class="nav-item"}}<a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>{{/link-to}}
    </ul>
  {{/if}}
```

My log-in action:

```
  this.transitionTo('dashboard');
```

Problem is that it transitions without updating the nav bar. Why is that? What can I do to run around this problem?

**Update regarding comments and first answer:**

What if I don't have an application controller? I have this so far in my application Route but it's still not updating even though I'm passing the data down to the nav bar component:

```
  simpleAuthManager: Ember.inject.service(),
  isAuthenticated: Ember.computed('simpleAuthManager', 'simpleAuthManager.user', function() {
    console.log(this.get('simpleAuthManager.user'));
    return this.get('simpleAuthManager').isAuthenticated();
  }),

  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('isAuthenticated', this.get('isAuthenticated'));
  }
```

Comment: You need to create a computed property called `isAuthenticated` in your application controller, and then update it using `notifyPropertyChange` whenever you log in or out so it always stays in sync.

Comment: I don’t think that would work. because you only call `setupController` on the application route once. you need a controller for this. or better yet, do it in the nav bar component. but remember to update the property so the view gets updated.

Comment: Awesome! It worked :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computed property is required to recompute the state every time `isAuthenticated` changes.

As I understand, you have a nav-bar child component present in your application template and have a service that manages the current logged-in/logged-out state of your application. Computed properties along with service injection can help you here.

Set up a computed property that watches your `isAuthenticated` variable from your service in your application controller (make a controller if you haven't). Pass the `isAuthenticated` as a parameter to your nav-bar component. In the nav-bar component inject the service as well, and have it set the authenticated state in an action every time a log-in/log-out link is clicked.

This way each time someone logs in or out your service is updated and as a consequence so is your `isAuthenticated` computed property in your application controller.

You can read up on Ember's computed properties [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/object-model/computed-properties/).